# Google Sheets: Referencing a Table on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I've been searching for an answer for this and I do not have one yet.
Let me provide you with an example of what I would like to do:

I have a table on one sheet of prices for colour x size of the shirt.
So for my table, on top are my sizes for the shirt (s, m, l, xl etc)
and on the left-hand side are my colours. Instead of having each colour/design have its own value, I want to make it so that those that are the same value, can share the same cell.

So on the left, it would be red/yellow in a2, black in a3, white/blue/gold/brown in a4 etc and so on.

That way on the main sheet if someone selects from the drop-down menus for colour (say blue) and size (say xl) it would pull the cost from the cell that corresponds with those two. But then if they did a white xl it would call from the same one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RWs9QbhPaoLy0oGTg99EfWbpFLm4MDYovy0lwNR2ODE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My bad!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RWs9QbhPaoLy0oGTg99EfWbpFLm4MDYovy0lwNR2ODE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RWs9QbhPaoLy0oGTg99EfWbpFLm4MDYovy0lwNR2ODE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to combine a IFS with a VLOOKUP.

So the idea is you'll use a VLOOKUP to find the row that has the style you want. Then depending on the size selected you're going to pick the column.

=VLOOKUP(stylecell, PriceSheet!A5:D25,IFS(sizecell="S",2, sizecell="M",3,sizecell="L",4),false)

1. Take the above code and replace the parts you need. Make the stylecell the specific cell where the user will pick the color/design they want.
2. PriceSheet is the name of the sheet that has the prices on it (I put an example data range but you'll want to include all your designs AND prices).
3. Make the sizecell the specific cell where the user will pick the size they want. IFS is a  function that lets you set up a bunch of cases. Here I've assumed the first column after the designs is the size "S" column. So, if the user pick "S" we will pick the price for "S" (value in column 2 of the data range you selected)
4. The final argument is going to tell VLOOKUP if it should be lenient or strict when looking for a match. If you're going to be having multiple style names in a single cell you'll want to set this to true.

Here is a full review of how to use VLOOKUP function:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/05/vlookup-google-sheets-example/

Here is some support for how to use the IFS function:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(Database!A2:A6, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&A2&"*", Database!A2:A6))), 
 Database!A2:G6, IFS(B2="Small",     2, 
                     B2="Medium",    3, 
                     B2="Large",     4, 
                     B2="X-Large",   5, 
                     B2="XX-Large",  6, 
                     B2="XXX-Large", 7), 0), )
```

[image]

Database sheet:

[image]