# Vlookup not able to find reference cell

Tags: google-sheets, match, importrange

I am using Google Sheets to look up a formula, but the code comes back saying

> "unable to match'.25oz'"

The link for the sheet is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K1Hb9xV8Ky51Vdiv0SG-zKOEH0ELPNBYwMWhDFfm4l0/edit#gid=168328825

The specific part I am having an error with is 'Master Cocktail' D5 where it tries to search either my Spirits sheet or the 'Beer NA Bev' sheet. for the appropriate price based on the oz used.

The code I am using in the cell is:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C5="","",vlookup($B5,{'Beer NA Bev'!$A$63:$H$71;Spirits!$A$2:$I$325},MATCH($C5,{'Beer NA Bev'!$A$62:$K$62;Spirits!$A$3:$J$3},0),FALSE)))
```

Comment: Cell D5 for example should pull the price from 'Beer NA Bev' Sheet row "Citrus, Limes".
So if C5 =.25oz then it would look for the price of .25oz lime juice in the 'Beer NA Bev' sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first of all `{'Beer NA Bev'!$A$63:$H$71; Spirits!$A$2:$I$325}` 
  needs to be: `{'Beer NA Bev'!$A$63:$I$71; Spirits!$A$2:$I$325}` eg. same amount of columns
- then you can drop the whole `MATCH` and put there `IFERROR` under which there will be `IF` with two `VLOOKUP` (one for `TRUE` side and one for `FALSE` side) to distinguish between beer and spirits because you have `.25oz` in both sheets. and then you can insert simple `IFS` to check/search for the right `.25oz` price and return column number for the main `VLOOKUP`.
   check this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680420/5632629

something like this:

```
 IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B5, 'Beer NA Bev'!$A$63:$I$71, 1, 0)<>"", IFS(C5=".25oz", 5, 
                                                                  C5=".5oz",  6, 
                                                                  C5=".75oz", 7, 
                                                                  C5="1oz",   8,
                                                                  C5="2oz",   9), ), 
         IF(VLOOKUP(B5, Spirits!$A$2:$I$325,       1, 0)<>"", IFS(C5="2oz",   4,
                                                                  C5="1.5oz", 5,
                                                                  C5="1oz",   6,
                                                                  C5=".75oz", 7,
                                                                  C5=".5oz",  8,
                                                                  C5=".25oz", 9), ))
```

and the whole formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C5="", "",
 VLOOKUP($B5, {'Beer NA Bev'!$A$63:$I$71;
                     Spirits!$A$2:$I$325},
 IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B5, 'Beer NA Bev'!$A$63:$I$71, 1, 0)<>"", IFS(C5=".25oz", 5, 
                                                                  C5=".5oz",  6, 
                                                                  C5=".75oz", 7, 
                                                                  C5="1oz",   8,
                                                                  C5="2oz",   9), ), 
         IF(VLOOKUP(B5, Spirits!$A$2:$I$325,       1, 0)<>"", IFS(C5="2oz",   4,
                                                                  C5="1.5oz", 5,
                                                                  C5="1oz",   6,
                                                                  C5=".75oz", 7,
                                                                  C5=".5oz",  8,
                                                                  C5=".25oz", 9), )), 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: So like this?
=if($A5="NAProduce",vlookup($B5,'Beer NA Bev'!$A$63:$A$71),Vlookup($B5,Spirits!$A$2:$A$325),IFS($C5='.25oz',5, 
$C5='.5oz,6, 
$C5='.75oz',7,
$C5=''1oz',8
$C5="'2oz',9),0),))"))